# AS3 How would I get an enemy to throw something?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs5

I wish to have an enemy throw a ball at the character. I want the ball to be sort of moving at a slow speed, and to arc. I am using AS3, and CS5.5. The thing I don't understand how to do is get the ball to exactly leave the enemies hands, or at least make it look like it. Also how to get the ball to travel on a curved path. Could someone explain how to do this?

Answer (score 0):

> how to do is get the ball to exactly leave the enemies hands

When you make the animation in Flash Professional (I'm assuming this is how your working) of the enemy throwing a ball, you need to link the ball animation as a separate MovieClip from the enemy (you can still use it inside the enemy movie). This allows you to reference it as a  separate class in AS3.

When the enemy goes to throw it, you'll need to know what frame of the enemy's animation to let go at. I'd use a frame-label, but you could manually just note the frame number as well.

To disconnect the ball from the enemy, you'll need to remove it as a child of the enemy MovieClip and add it to the 'level' or whatever parent the enemy itself has. Note: While it was a child of the enemy, it inherited the enemy's translation; you'll need to offset its position in the level by the enemy's position manually now that it is no longer a child.

> how to get the ball to travel on a curved path.

This could be done via animating the ball in Flash Professional with a tween, or other animation tools. That way, when you release it from the enemy you just need to play its animation.

Alternatively, you can manually translate each frame with a equation based on '[projectile motion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion)'.